# Chat application nodejs on a website in apache

Tags: node.js, apache, mean-stack, lamp

I have a question
I have a website that uses LAMP technologies (Linux, Apache, mysql, php) and I would like to implement a chat that is created in MEAN technology (MongoDB, Express, Angular and nodeJS).
I know that apache does not interpret nodejs, so I have two servers (apache and nodejs) but I would like that when they enter my LAMP website, this will present the welcome chat in MEAN. How can I create this combination between the two servers?
I want to create something similar to https://www.livechatinc.com/ for my website.
Thank you very much for your help!
Sorry for my terrible English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding is that you need a proxy pass in your Apache configuration.

Anyway, your MEAN application runs on specific localhost/port and you need proxy pass configuration.

If your chat is on your welcome page, you need to proxying to this page.

Hope it can help.